# Solve the triple integral $\iiint_{K}\left(x^{2}-z^{2}\right) d x d y d z$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

How does one go about solving the integral:

$\iiint_{K}\left(x^{2}-z^{2}\right) d x \,d y \,d z$

where K is the body that is given by

$x \geq 0,\: y \geq 0,\: z \geq 0$ and $x+y+z \leq 1$

I assume I am to convert this to spherical coordinates but I'm really unsure as to how to proceed.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: I would suggest that it might not be very appropriate to use spherical coordinates here since spherical coordinates are often used when integrating a body with some sort of spherical symmetry, but in this case, $x+y+z=1$ is a plane and doesn't have much spherical symmetry, so maybe sticking to cartesian coordinates would be more straightforward in this case. Last but not least welcome to Math SE!

Comment: By symmetry this integral has trivially the value $0$.

Answer (score 2):

No need for spherical coordinates. If we let y vary between 0 and 1, x,z must obey that

$x+z \le 1-y$

In a similar way, holding y constant, if we vary x from 0 to 1-y, we have that

$z \le 1-y-x$

Therefore, we can rewrite your integral as

$\int_0^1\int_0^{1-y}\int_0^{1-y-x}x^2 - z^2 dzdxdy$

Now simply integrate in the order prescribed (that is, first with respect to z, then x and lastly y), and you will get your result.

Comment: +1 Curiously, by the time you evaluate the second integral, the result is already $0$.

Comment: I hadn't even thought about the symmetry of the integrand and the area of integrations, you're right! Maybe a symmetry argument would be prettier.